# Cannot read property : style of Null

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Trello Board using Vanilla Javascript and I am receiving an error on making my Cards . I have used Local and Session Storage to store the cards and lists respectively but I can't figure out why this error persists after I click on the Add Card Board Button

```
function newTask(x){
        card_index= parseInt(localStorage.getItem("card_indices")) ;
        //card_index = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("card_indices"));
        list_index = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("index"));
        document.getElementById('myTasks').innerHTML +=
        '<div id = "list_' + list_index + ' " class="list-item animated zoomIn" > <h2 id = "title_' + list_index +'" onClick = "modifyObj.titleEdit('+ list_index +')" class="list-item__h2">'+x+'</h2><span id = "span_del_' + list_index + '" class ="btn title-delete" onClick ="modifyObj.titleDelete(' + list_index + ')">\u00D7</span><hr>'+
        '<input  id = "card_del_' + card_index + '" type="text" class="myInput" placeholder="Title...">' +
        '<div class="btn add-items " id = "div_add_list_"  onClick = "myCard.titleForm(' + list_index + ',' + card_index + ')" >Add List Item</div>'
        '</div>'
        sessionStorage.setItem("index", parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("index"))+1);

    }
```

```
var myCard = {

         card:function(index, card_index){


             var enteredElement = document.getElementById('card_del_' + card_index).value;

             var textNode = document.getElementsByClassName('text_' + card_index);


                    textNode.innerText = enteredElement;


             if (enteredElement === ""){
                 alert("You must write something ");
                 }
             else{
                  document.getElementById("text_").style.display = "block";

                 }
         },


   titleForm: function(index,card_index){
       element = document.getElementById('card_del_' + card_index);

       text = '<li style="display:none" class="text_'+ card_index +'"> <span class = "btn items" onClick = "myCard.cardClose()">u00D7</span></li>'

       element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', text);
        myCard.card(index,card_index);         
           localStorage.setItem("card_indices", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("card_indices"))+1); 
             // card_index+=1;

    }};
```

Comment: textNode.innerText = enteredElement;
 This value is coming out to be Null but it should contain the value of the enteredElement i.e the inputValue

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Well, a separate (perhaps) issue is that this line:

    `var textNode = document.getElementsByClassName('text_' + card_index);`

returns a node list (collection) and then you try on the next line to do this:

   `textNode.innerText = enteredElement;`

You are trying to get the `innerText` property of a collection, rather than one of the nodes within that collection. A node list doesn't have an `.innerText` property

Comment: Yes, thankyou Scott, the problem here was a trivial one though , document.getElementById("text_").style.display = "block"; 
needed an inclusion of "text_"+ index.